# How to achieve a WinForm with one fixed size and one variable column?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, tablelayout, tablelayoutpanel

I'm trying to this with the `TableLayout` control, and have one column fixed at 200 and the other AutoSize. Yet unless I place anything in the autosize column, it shrinks to nothing, and the other supposedly fixed width column expands over the whole form.

Do I really have to manually resize two bloody panels at every form resize to achieve this? I thought we lived in modern times.

Comment: "Modern times" would look more like WPF ;) Anyway, it would be easier to answer your question if we could see what your code currently looks like.

Comment: Are you sure you put 200 px and not 200 percent?

Comment: Yes, I put 200px. @PatriceGahide, WPF + VB.NET is the Devil. I have no code yet, I', still trying to get the layout control working on the page. That sholdn't need code, or I would just write my own bloody control

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Autosize behaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171690%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you should use Percent rather than Autosize :

> After space for all Absolute and AutoSize columns or rows is allocated, any columns or rows with SizeType set to Percent are used to proportionally allocate the remaining free space

Autosize will match the widest child element it can find, so it is logical that when there is no child found, the chosen column width is 0.
FI, this behaviour is the same in WPF when a size is set at "Auto".

Answer (score 3):

Set the other column (the AutoSize) one to 100%.

Comment: That makes _perfect_ sense, thanks.